# Word for one who plays flute?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Is the correct term for a person with the ability to play the flute a "flutist" or a "flautist"?

Comment: Can you give more context? Correct in what way? Formal or informal?

Comment: I know several flute players some who say they are flautists and some who say they are flutists.  It’s a personal preference thing.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flautist%2Cflutist&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflautist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflutist%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I think the answer to this question was given in Woody Allen´s "Life without Zoe", but I cannot find the script right now.

Comment: I think the answer to this question can be found in a dictionary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is an interesting article](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/flautist-or-flutist/).

It seems that Americans prefer *flutist*, although it was an American, Nicholas Hawthorn who first used *flautist* in 1860, in his novel *the Marble Faun*. It is said that it could be that Hawthorn did this to add local colour, since it was set in Italy, where the Italian for flute is *flauto*.

*Flutist* is an older English rendering, originating from the French. Modern French has the name of the instrument as *flûte*. But it seems the further south you go *flaut...* takes over - Provencal and Spanish - *flauta*, Italian *flauto*.

So, I think it is a case of "you pays your money and you takes your choice". But if I was speaking to a serious musician I would feel more comfortable describing them as a *flautist*, for fear of offending them. But that may just be my own prejudice.

In practice orchestral players are usually described by the name of their instrument. Orchestras speak of their "principal flute", or list the names of their "cellos" etc.

Answer (score -1):

Either term is correct. The two are synonymous. The former is preferred in the United States; the latter, elsewhere.

Comment: I believe you, but I have never seen the word flautist, ever. And I am from elsewhere ;)